# Runtime Version of DLL is not changing

Tags: .net, frameworks, version

When I view the properties of my dll referenced inside visual studio I see that the Runtime Version is v2.0.50727.   I have recompiled the dll to target version 3.5 of the .net framework and reimported the dll, but the Runtime Version is still v2.0.50727.  I think there is something I don't understand.  Can someone explain why it isn't 3.5 now.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

.NET 3.5 still uses the .NET 2.0 CLR - and that's the version number you're seeing.

I believe that updating from .NET 2.0 to .NET 3.5 actually updates the CLR, but you can *mostly* think of .NET 3.5 as an extra set of libraries on top of the same runtime.

Answer (score 3):

.NET 3.5 is built on top of .NET 2.0 and uses some of the same assemblies.  You are probably looking at an assembly that is the same.

See [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a starting point.